# Ant 1.9.3 and jenkins 1_539 installation issue

Tags: ant, jenkins

I'm trying to add a build job to jenkins for a project mounted in gitlab using ant. For ant installation in jenkins I choose install from apache and version 1.9.3, I configured jenkins to fetch the master branch from git and that was working well, but when I try to build the project I have this error :

> hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to install http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip to /root/.jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/ant1.9.3
>       at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:769)
>       at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:70)
>       at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:61)
>       at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:107)
>       at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:204)
>       at hudson.tasks.Ant$AntInstallation.forNode(Ant.java:375)
>       at hudson.tasks.Ant.perform(Ant.java:151)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:781)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
>       at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:562)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1679)
>       at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:230)
>   Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to unpack http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip (934 bytes read of total 934)
>       at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:763)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive

can any one please show me a fixe for this or an alternative to install ant on jenkins.

Comment: I would guess it to be a proxy/firewall problem. Do you use a proxy? Try doing `wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.3-bin.zip` from console and check whether the result is really a zip file (or maybe a html page stateting "not found"?)

Comment: Hi, No the problem is not related to firewall, I tried the command and it return the correct zip file, I guess this is an unzipping issue with jenkins.

Comment: could you try a different ant version and see if the problem remains?

Comment: Hi I did this actually I found the LSP containing this issue but there is no patching for it you have to upgrade jenkins version, but unfortunately its not that easy because we have many maven projects running on it. So I have to find an alternative solution.

Comment: You could try to download the zip file, put it somewhere on your webserver (JENKINS_HOME/userContent) and try one of the other autoinstall options. Since wget does work, run script should work in any case.